# How to setup check box to accept 0 or 1 for values from database

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have HTML table inside the each td i have drop down and check box i am linked it with database in database i have table name checkbox( its value are 1 and 0)but what i want to show if the value in 1, i want to display the check box as checked if 0 unchecked.

Can anyone guide me

td for checkbox:

```
<td style="width:200px" id="CPH_GridView1_Status1'.$rows['net_id'].'" class="updateseleniumroute status1 '.$rows["net_id"].' ">
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin:0 0 0 93px;" name=""/></td>
```

Comment: what's to set up? give it a `value` attribute, and `checked` or not if the values's 1 or 0...

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="checkbox" <?php if ($dbFlag == 1) echo "checked"; ?>/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Added php condition `<?php echo $value=='1'?'checked':'';?>`. `$value` from table

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin:0 0 0 93px;" name=""   <?php echo $value=='1'?'checked':'';?> />
```